# How many users must vote to reopen a question that is on-hold?

Tags: support, closed-questions, reopen-request, vote-to-close

I found this in the help center:

> Who can put questions "on hold"?
>
> Users with 3000 reputation can cast up to 24 close votes per day. When
>   a question reaches 5 close votes, it is marked [on hold], and will no
>   longer accept answers. Those users may vote to reopen questions the
>   same way. Each user may only vote to close and reopen a given question
>   once. (For example, if you vote to close a question that is closed and
>   then later reopened, you cannot vote to close it again.)

My question is: Are the number of votes needed to reopen a question once it's been edited equivalent to the number of original close votes?  If not, how many votes are needed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It takes 5 reopen votes.

Interestingly this isn't specifically said in the help center anywhere I can find.

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR: **It takes 5 votes to reopen a question.**

The Help Center link on the "[on hold / closed]" post notice links to [*"What does it mean if a question is "closed" or "on hold"?"*](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions) which says:

> Users with 3000 reputation can cast up to 24 close votes per day. When a question reaches **5 close votes**, it is marked [on hold], and will no longer accept answers. **Those users<sup>1</sup> may vote to reopen questions the same way.**
>
> Moderators may close or reopen any question with a single vote.

This page then points to a more detailed help section on reopening: ["What if I disagree with the closure of a question? How can I reopen it?"](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/reopen-questions). That says the following:

> Reopening a question follows the same process as closing a question.
>
> Users with 3,000 reputation can cast up to 24 reopen votes per day. **When a question reaches 5 reopen votes, it is no longer closed**, and new answers may be submitted. You may only vote to close or reopen a question once. To cast a reopen vote, click the "reopen" link beneath the question.
>
> Moderators may close or reopen any question with a single vote

---

<sup>1 - Referring to users with 3k reputation or more, not the users who originally voted to close.</sup>

Comment: Are moderators allowed to close or reopen a question multiple times?

Comment: @MaskedMan-仮面の男 I assume so, since the moderators are listed separately from the users and it does say "any question". Few if any of the anti-abuse measures apply to moderators I think.